# Define word wrapping for a SimpleLabelStyle

Tags: html, yfiles

I am trying to create a `SimpleLabelStyle` with the `word wrapping` enabled, as the second box of the [interactive demo](http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/1.3/tutorials/01_Getting_Started/18_Label_Text_Wrapping/index.html). However, I am not able to reproduce it.

I am trying:

```
var /**yfiles.drawing.SimpleLabelStyle*/ simpleLabelStyle = new yfiles.drawing.SimpleLabelStyle();
simpleLabelStyle.trimming = yfiles.system.StringTrimming.WORD;
```

But it's not working. In fact, in the [documentation](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtmlv2/#/api/yfiles.drawing.SimpleLabelStyle#SimpleLabelStyle-property-trimming), I see that trimming "***gets*** the value that determines how to trim the text." (it just says "gets" and not "sets").

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you *can* set the value - this documentation is misleading here. The property is declared `READ-ONLY` **in the interface** (see the badge):

[ISimpleLabelStyle.trimming API](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtmlv2/#/api/yfiles.drawing.ISimpleLabelStyle#ISimpleLabelStyle-property-trimming)

But the instance that you have instanciated implements the interface and makes the property `READ-WRITE`. Unfortunately the documentation is inherited from the interface and the only indication that the property is READ-WRITE is that the `READ-ONLY` badge is missing in the API browser. Any property that is not `READ-ONLY` or `WRITE-ONLY` is implicitly readable and writable so setting the value *will* work using the property on the instance ([SimpleLabelStyle.trimming API](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtmlv2/#/api/yfiles.drawing.SimpleLabelStyle#SimpleLabelStyle-property-trimming))

Note that if you are changing the value for an existing style, the change will not immediately be visible. You should invalidate the graph's displays using the 
[IGraph.invalidateDisplays() API](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtmlv2/#/api/yfiles.graph.IGraph#IGraph-method-invalidateDisplays)

```
var style = new yfiles.drawing.SimpleLabelStyle() 
style.trimming = yfiles.system.StringTrimming.ELLIPSIS_WORD;
graph.setLabelStyle(label, style);

// and later
style.trimming = yfiles.system.StringTrimming.ELLIPSIS_CHARACTER;
graph.invalidateDisplays();
```

Answer (score 0):

`trimming` is read-only, as indicated [here](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtmlv2/#/api/yfiles.drawing.ISimpleLabelStyle#ISimpleLabelStyle-property-trimming), so you can't use it to set anything.

It appears that it's not intended to set a wrapping style for a `simpleLabelStyle` object directly as it provides neither a parameter not a function to do so, but you can set it at the time you add text to it. The [addText](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtmlv2/#/api/yfiles.drawing.TextRenderSupport#TextRenderSupport-method-addText) and [placeText](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileshtmlv2/#/api/yfiles.drawing.TextRenderSupport#TextRenderSupport-method-placeText) functions allow you to pass a trimming parameter, which will take the `WORD` argument.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense, indeed. I will try as soon as I can and let you now!

Comment: OK, I am trying the approach suggested, but both `addText` and `placeText` require a `SVGTextElement` parameter, and I have literally no idea how to set that. I am trying `yfiles.drawing.TextRenderSupport.addText(node1, "Test with long text", c, new yfiles.geometry.SizeD(10, 10), yfiles.system.StringTrimming.WORD);`, with `c` being a `Typeface` previously defined, and `node1` my `INode` instance (I know, it's wrong, cause is not a `SVGTextElement`. Do you have any insights? Thank you.

Comment: @Andrea: I was under the impression that you would need to provide your `SimpleLabelStyle` element, so in your original example, that would be the element stores in the `simpleLabelStyle` variable. The individual elements are SVG elements, so that's why they're named in such a way in the documentation (though as already established, the documentation isn't what you would call exhaustive...)